# Jsoup imdb rating

Tags: java, jsoup

I wrote a program which reads the name and the rating of the top 250 movies on imdb and return the mean of the rating. I have the follow program

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class da {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {


            Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top").get();
            Elements e=doc.getElementsByClass("titleColumn");
            Elements t=doc.getElementsByClass("imdbRating");
            float suma=0;
        for(int i=0;i<e.size();i++)
            suma=suma+Float.parseFloat(t.get(i).text());

    System.out.println(suma/250);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

My question is why in 't' it needs "imdbRating" because if i look in the html on the page i see that where rating is located it writes "ratingColumn imdbRating" (i did this program by mistake and i don't know why it is working this way and not the other way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the element `e` in this program. The `titleColumn` in the webpage just contains the title of the movie. Considering you only need the ratings, this is unnecessary. You can just use the `t` element when I renamed to `ratings` and cleaned up your code a little bit:

```
    import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class da {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top").get();
            Elements ratings = doc.select(".ratingColumn.imdbRating");

            float suma = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < ratings.size(); i++)
                suma = suma + Float.parseFloat(ratings.get(i).child(0).text());

            System.out.println(suma/250);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

**EDIT:** To select elements with multiple classes, you must use `doc#select` and pass it a CSS query like above.

Comment: i wanted to use the names for other things but i had problems with rating and decided to delete that part and let only rating

Comment: So what exactly is your question then?

Comment: why using "ratingColumn imdbRating" did not work? it is not this the column name or what?

Comment: You have to use `select`. I edited my answer with working code.

Comment: ok then. but why my version doesn't work? i saw something at the other answer but i did't understand very well.can you give me an example of an element from that page (for example when i use getelementsbyclass what element does it return)?

Comment: The URL currently shows the top 250 but what if IMDB decides on a different number?  Should it be System.out.println(sum/ratings.size()) ?

Comment: yes but is was an example and i was facing others problem. this is my last problem if i don't understand why it is working this way and not the other way. i could get the number of movies as well if i understand what is the matter with select and what getelements...(all this functions) does because i think i don't understand very well

Comment: It's just not how the class was built. If you're interested in finding out more, Jsoup is open source. Take a look at line 657 of [this class](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/f5ddda0a3ed0c0a8adf4e74dcb230bb609a2717f/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.java) to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

nicholas79171 has a good answer, but I would just like to point out that you can use [CSS Selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to target the ratings directly, without all of the dom traversal methods.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top").get();

    float ratingSum = 0;

    Elements ratings = doc.select("td.ratingColumn.imdbRating > strong");

    for (Element rating : ratings)
        ratingSum += Float.parseFloat(rating.ownText());

    System.out.println(ratingSum / ratings.size());
```

Comment: but what dom traversal methods doing? (sorry for lacking of knowledge but i started to learn this and i want to find a fast way of solving this problems and along with this to understand what really happens and why it is working or not)

Comment: @User124235 the DOM (Document Object Model) is basically a large tree structure.  Think of it like this, if you wanted to get to a particular leaf of a tree, you could climb the trunk, climb out on a large branch, climb to smaller branches, and eventually get to the leaf.  With CSS selectors, we can go right to the leaf we want using a ladder.  Both will get you to the leaf, but CSS selectors generally leave your code cleaner and doesn't require as much error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `getElementsByClass` to get an element which contain multiple classes; it only works singularly; If you wanted to get them with multiple elements you might use `select` on your `Document`. You can read more about how select works [here](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).